# Example of Continuous Random Variable Distribution, with Median=Mean but not Symmetric?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

So I recently learned that for a random variable that has **Median $=$ Mean**, symmetry of the density function around the mean is not implied. I found this to be surprising as the common continuous distributions that I am aware of (Uniform, Normal, etc) that have equal median and mean are symmetric.

I had initially thought of the Gamma distribution as a possibility, however unless I am mistaken, the Mean can approach the Median under certain specifications, but will always be slightly larger.

I am curious if anyone can think of continuous random variable distributions that have an equal median and mean, but are not symmetric about the mean?

Comment: here an example provided https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239171/why-are-mean-and-median-not-equal-for-asymmetric-distributions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a density like this

$$f(x)= 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac1{8} &\quad\text{if } 0 \le x \lt 4 \\
       \frac14 &\quad\text{if } 4 \le x \lt 5 \\
       \frac1{20} &\quad\text{if } 5 \le x \lt 10 \\
       0 &\quad\text{otherwise } \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

which has a mean and median of $4$ and looks like

[image: mean equals median]

Comment: Good suggestion. For some reason, I was thinking that the PDF would need to be continuous, but I realize now that need not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from the point of view of [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem):

There exist two distinct probability measures $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ on $[0, \infty)$ such that their moment sequences coincide.  Then consider the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ it's $\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1 + \mu_2')$ ( that is, on the positive axis $\frac{1}{2} \mu_1$, on the negative axis $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \mu_2'$, the reflexion on $\mu_2$.  Then we see that the origin is the "median" for all of the absolute moments, yet the measure $\mu$ is not symmetric.